React Native getting React-Fabric error after upgrade to 74
I'm trying to make some updates to an older project and facing the normal headaches that come with supporting the updates to new iOS versions. After running some npm updates and a react native upgrade I was able to successfully pod install, but now when I run-ios it fails to build with the following error:
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ [RN]Check\ rncore .../Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Fabric.build/Script-EC9C377125AD0589400F123D2D4CB2D3.sh (in target 'React-Fabric' from project 'Pods')

Here's my react native info:
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
  OS: macOS 14.5
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M3
  Memory: 82.38 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.16.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/bin/node
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 10.8.1
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.07.29.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.15.2
    path: /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.5
      - iOS 17.5
      - macOS 14.5
      - tvOS 17.5
      - visionOS 1.2
      - watchOS 10.5
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2024.1 AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903
  Xcode:
    version: 15.4/15F31d
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.12
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 3.3.4
    path: /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.74.5
    wanted: 0.74.5
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: false
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: false
  newArchEnabled: false



Any ideas where I can begin to resolve this issue?
UPDATE
After digging a bit deeper here's the build file that's failing:
echo "Checking whether Codegen has run..."
rncorePath="$REACT_NATIVE_PATH/ReactCommon/react/renderer/components/rncore"

if [[ ! -d "$rncorePath" ]]; then
  echo 'error: Codegen did not run properly in your project. Please reinstall cocoapods with `bundle exec pod install`.'
  exit 1
fi

So for some reason that $REACT_NATIVE_PATH/ReactCommon/react/renderer/components/rncore path does not exist. I'm not sure why and I'll continue to research.

It seems the codegen was not working due to some pods trying to use minimum support versions less than that specified in my Podfile. I'm not sure why that was but I came across a github issue with a fix linked below.
https://github.com/travis-mark/lrn/commit/015854716feadd61a904d5a603b027426472f863
The fix is a post install script that overrides the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET with the minimum ios version from the Podfile.
Builds are working now
